# How to center pdf file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion

I'm using Synfusion_pdf_viewer package and I'm trying to display my local PDF file but some reason it's not displaying the way I wanted.

I wanted the page to be center but it look like it's going all the way to the right side. I have try to play around with the plugin but no success yet so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PdfViewer'),
          actions: <Widget>[],
        ),
        body: SfPdfViewer.asset(
          'data/hymn_pdf/full-songs.pdf',
          initialZoomLevel: 1.5,
          initialScrollOffset: Offset.fromDirection(10),
          controller: _pdfViewerController,
          pageSpacing: 10,
          canShowScrollHead: false,
          onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
            _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(widget.number); // jump to page 3
          },
        ));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a bound with sizedbox

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PdfViewer'),
          actions: <Widget>[],
        ),
        body:SizedBox(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child : Center(
         child: SfPdfViewer.asset(
          'data/hymn_pdf/full-songs.pdf',
          initialZoomLevel: 1.5,
          initialScrollOffset: Offset.fromDirection(10),
          controller: _pdfViewerController,
          pageSpacing: 10,
          canShowScrollHead: false,
          onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
            _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(widget.number); // jump to page 3
          },
        ),
       )
      )
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can direct wrap to the center widget and it's working fine.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PdfViewer'),
          actions: <Widget>[],
      **strong text**),
      body: Center(
          child: _isLoading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : SfPdfViewer.asset(
          'data/hymn_pdf/full-songs.pdf',
          initialZoomLevel: 1.5,
          initialScrollOffset: Offset.fromDirection(10),
          controller: _pdfViewerController,
          pageSpacing: 10,
          canShowScrollHead: false,
          onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
            _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(widget.number); // jump to page 3
          },
        ));,
    );
  }
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

We have included the fix for this issue “The PDF pages are not aligned properly when setting the initialZoomLevel API in SfPdfViewer” in our latest Volume 2 SP release, so kindly upgrade to the latest version v20.2.43 to get the issue resolved.

Package link: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/versions/20.2.43-beta